# Select processes by user and command name using ps

Tags: linux, proc, ps

I try to find all processes created by root and whose command name is httpd for example.

```
# ps -U root -u root -C httpd -o pid,vsize,cmd,user | tail
```

```
32445 371488 /opt/apache_aux2_pool610/2. 743905
32490      0 [kworker/u66:2]             root
32493 1404904 /opt/apache_aux3_pool602/2. www
32513 359256 /opt/apache_aux5_pool610/2. 693693
32520 393904 /opt/apache_aux4_pool605/2. root
32595 395688 /opt/apache_aux4_pool608/2. w_buzlakov_83569e04
32627 403820 /opt/apache_aux4_pool607/2. 20012412
32656 437580 /opt/apache_aux4_pool603/2. 20022253
32698 385876 /opt/apache_own/current/sbi 20063363
32761 811756 /opt/apache_aux4_pool4/2.2. www
```

but ps with the given above arguments outputs all processes. There is an impression that it fully ignores **"-U root -u root -C httpd"** options. Is this correct work ps or I was wrong somewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming; it probably belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: a workaround can be pipe the output of ps into grep e.g. `ps -C httpd -o pid,vsize,cmd,user | grep root`

Comment: `ps` is not ignoring the options. It uses an `or` condition for the options. So it will show a process if it run as root or if it's command is httpd. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84486/is-there-a-way-to-select-by-several-conditions-in-ps for alternatives.